# How correctly add fields to all the object of an array of FireStore documents using RxJS?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I am going crazy with the following RxJS problem.

Into  an Angular service class I originally had this method retrieving data from Firebase FireStore database:

```
async getAllEmployees() { 
    return <Observable<User[]>> this.firestore.collection('users',ref => ref.where('profileType', '!=', 'admin')).valueChanges();          
  }
```

returning an Observable containing an array of **User** objects. This works fine.

This service method is called by a component TypeScript code method, this one:

```
async loadEmployeesList() {
    this.employeesList$ = await this.employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    console.log("employeesList$: ", this.employeesList$);
}
```

Now I have the following problem: I have to add a calculated field to each objects retrieved by FireStore. This field name is **completedName** and is the concatenation of the following two fields: **firstName** and **surname**.

So I tried to do in the following way using RxJS:

```
  async getAllEmployees() { 
    //return <Observable<Employee[]>> this.firestore.collection('users',ref => ref.where('profileType', '!=', 'admin')).valueChanges(); 
    
    return <Observable<Employee[]>> <unknown>this.firestore.collection('users', ref => ref.where('isEmployee', '==', true)).snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe(snaps => {
        snaps.map(snap => {
          console.log("CURRENT SNAP: ", snap);

          let currentEmployee: Employee = {
            id: snap.payload.doc.id,
            firstName: snap.payload.doc.get("firstName"),
            surname: snap.payload.doc.get("surname"),
            completeName: snap.payload.doc.get("firstName") + " " + snap.payload.doc.get("surname"),
            placeOfBirth: snap.payload.doc.get("placeOfBirth"),
            socialSecurityCode: snap.payload.doc.get("socialSecurityCode"),
            birthDate: snap.payload.doc.get("birthDate"),
            companyEmail: snap.payload.doc.get("companyEmail"),
            personalEmail: snap.payload.doc.get("personalEmail"),
            companyPhone: snap.payload.doc.get("companyPhone"),
            personalPhone: snap.payload.doc.get("personalPhone"),
            selectedEmployeeStatus: snap.payload.doc.get("selectedEmployeeStatus"),
            isEmployee: snap.payload.doc.get("isEmployee"),
            isAdmin: snap.payload.doc.get("isAdmin"),
          };

          console.log("currentEmployee: ", currentEmployee);

          return currentEmployee;
        });
      });
      
                                                        
                                                        
  }
```

This methoditerate on each **Employee[]** objects and retrieved from FireStore and add the following two fields to the original object:

```
id: snap.payload.doc.id,
```

and

```
completeName: snap.payload.doc.get("firstName") + " " + snap.payload.doc.get("surname"),
```

returning the modified object.

The problem now is that my application broke and in the browser console I am obtaining this error message:

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:4154)
    at AsyncPipe._selectStrategy (common.js:4256)
    at AsyncPipe._subscribe (common.js:4246)
    at AsyncPipe.transform (common.js:4234)
    at Module.ɵɵpipeBind1 (core.js:24743)
    at EmployeeListComponent_Template (employee-list.component.html:31)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:7457)
    at refreshView (core.js:7326)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8473)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:7132)
```

I think that the problem is due to the fact that in the Angular component that call my service method:

```
// Load the list of all the employees:
async loadEmployeesList() {
    this.employeesList$ = await this.employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    console.log("employeesList$: ", this.employeesList$);
}
```

I am receiving no more an **Observable** but I am obtaining a **Subscriber** object (I can see it using the console.log())

How can I fix my code in order to return an Observable containing an array with the modified objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribing to a stream returns its subscription.

```
const stream = of(1,2,3,4);
const subscription = stream.subscribe();
```

You're subscribing and then returning that subscription

```
return stream.subscribe();
```

It looks like what you want to do is map each element in your stream into a new element. If that's the case, you shouldn't `subscribe`, you should `observable#map`.

What surprises me is that in your last question you actually did `map` your `userObject`, so I'm not sure what inspired the change here when mapping an array.

The exact same approach works, only now you're mapping an array rather than an object. `map(array => array.map(...))` is pretty common in RxJS

```js
getAllEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]> { 
  //return <Observable<Employee[]>> this.firestore.collection('users',ref => ref.where('profileType', '!=', 'admin')).valueChanges(); 
    
  return <Observable<Employee[]>> <unknown>this.firestore.collection(
    'users', 
    ref => ref.where('isEmployee', '==', true)
  ).snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(snaps => 
      snaps
        .map(snap => snap.payload.doc)
        .map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id,
          firstName: doc.get("firstName"),
          surname: doc.get("surname"),
          completeName: `${doc.get("firstName")} ${doc.get("surname")}`,
          placeOfBirth: doc.get("placeOfBirth"),
          socialSecurityCode: doc.get("socialSecurityCode"),
          birthDate: doc.get("birthDate"),
          companyEmail: doc.get("companyEmail"),
          personalEmail: doc.get("personalEmail"),
          companyPhone: doc.get("companyPhone"),
          personalPhone: doc.get("personalPhone"),
          selectedEmployeeStatus: doc.get("selectedEmployeeStatus"),
          isEmployee: doc.get("isEmployee"),
          isAdmin: doc.get("isAdmin")
        }))
    )
  );
}
```